# wp_mail sending only plain text messages

Tags: html, wordpress, email

I am sending some emails using wp_mail() function to send some HTML formatted emails. The problem is that the emails all look like basic plain text.

I set my headers to

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

In Windows, I use Fake SMTP server to test. The Content/Type is being recognized as `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

The problem is that all my emails look like basic plain text. No spacing from divs, no tables, no CSS modifications, nothing. It basically takes the text from the HTML that I wrote and puts it inline. I also tried sending the emails to GMAIL and no luck, it looks the same.

I ran out of options with testing this. What should I change?

Comment: I found the reasons for my problems: 1. The `strip_tags()` function for wrapping my message. and 2. I didn't know that a plugin can modify any HTML that you send. So if you are in a similar situation, also check any email plugins that you have.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled HTML Headers in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail', function( $params ) {
  $params['headers'] = 'Content-type: text/html';
  return $params;
} );
```